# jQuery function on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a custom function that triggers when I hover an element.
The usual (I think) solution for this would just to select the element and .hover(function)
I want to create a function that looks like this:

```
name(element,inColor,outColor,time)
{
    element.hover(animate{color:inColor,duration:time},{animate:outColor,duration:time})
}
```

and just call this function on every element which I want to animate. Problem is I have to pin this to an event and can't just say

```
name($("a"),"#000","#fff",250);
```

I just can't figure out how to make the function trigger on hover.
Is this possible and since it's a two liner, does it deserve a function on its own?

Comment: you can not animate color! you need to use CSS3 transition in order to be able to do that

Comment: I am using jQuery-color plugin from the jQueryUI library, forgot to mention that. The function works when I do it the "normal" way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is with your syntax.

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) accepts two **functions** to complete `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`, respectively.

Let's take a look at your function:

```
element.hover(animate{color:inColor,duration:time},{animate:outColor,duration:time})
```

`animate{...}` is not the proper way to call the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. Also, `duration` should be outside the object, as it is not a CSS property (you're mixing up the two different ways of calling `animate()`: I'm assuming you want `.animate(plainObject properties, duration time)`, but check the documentation I've linked to if you want the other one). It should look something more like this:

```
element.hover(function(){ $(this).animate({color:inColor,}, time); }, ... );
```

Now for the second part: `{animate:outColor, duration:time}`. This isn't going to work at all. What you're looking for is this:

```
function(){ $(this).animate({color:outColor}, time); }
```

Together:

```
element.hover(function(){ $(this).animate({color:inColor,}, time); }, function(){ $(this).animate({color:outColor,}, time); });
```

If you want a nicely formatted/readable version:

```
function name(element, inColor, outColor, time) {
    element.hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            color: inColor,
        }, time);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            color: outColor,
        }, time);
    });
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/rf8b4179/)

Comment: thanks for the downvote (I don't know why!?), you know this is not a contest!?

Comment: @user1934618 I did not downvote your answer (hundreds of thousands of people visit this site every day and, despite the fact that we're the only ones talking, almost 50 people have viewed this question). I was going to upvote it, actually.

Comment: anyway, +1 from me as you put a lot of effort in your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
function name(element,inColor,outColor,time) {
    element.hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({color:inColor}, time)
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({color:outColor}, time)
    });
}

name($("a"), "#000", "#fff", 250);
```

Comment: +1 from me, this should answer the question.. rather than just point in the right direction :)